# Tips for golfing in OCaml

Tags: code-golf, tips

Inspired from the assortment of other 'Tips for golfing in language xyz'. As usual, please only suggest tips that are specific to OCaml and not programming in general. One tip per answer please.

Answer (score 4):

### Use functions instead of match

```
let rec f=function[]->0|_::t->1+f t
```

is shorter than

```
let rec f x=match x with[]->0|_::t->1+f t
```

Answer (score 3):

### Never use begin […] end

This:

```
begin […] end
```

is always synonymous with this:

```
([…])
```

Answer (score 2):

### Define several variables or functions at once

Thanks to tuples, you can define several variables at once. And as functions are first-class citizens…:

```
let f,g=(fun x->x+1),fun x->2*x
```

You can’t, however, write:

```
let f,g=(fun x->x+1),fun x->2*f x
```

> Error: Unbound value f

Unfortunately, you can’t avoid the issue by using `rec`:

```
let rec f,g=(fun x->x+1),fun x->2*f x
```

> Error: Only variables are allowed as left-hand side of `let rec`

Answer (score 2):

### Exploit [curryied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) functions

Functions in OCaml are curryied. It might be useful to exploit that fact sometimes.

```
let n y=f x y
```

can be written

```
let n=f x
```

If you need arithmetic operations, you can surround them with parentheses so they behave like standard, prefix functions. `(+)`, `(-)`, …

```
let n=(+)1;;
n 3;;
```

> `- : int = 4`

Answer (score 1):

## `downto`

If you're not sure how to loop downwards, `downto` is usually the one to go for. Instead of:

```
for i=0 to 1000 do
Printf.printf"%d
"(1000-i)
done
```

You can do:

```
for i=1000 downto 0 do
Printf.printf"%d
"i
done
```

Comment: you could also do something like `for i= -1000 to 0`. Also, your syntax for these programs is missing the `do done` parts

Answer (score 0):

## `print_string`

Instead of the usual `Printf.printf""`, you can actually use the below (ONLY for strings, no formatting):

```
print_string"wassup"
```

Which is 1 byte shorter than:

```
Printf.printf"wassup"
```

Comment: Is this really worth a tip? It isn't normal to use `Printf.printf` for raw strings anyway